# Different delay time for different agents in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'd like to know a very simple function of the software Anylogic: I have to set different delay times for different agents in a model, but the software let me see only one boxe and there's no possibilities to specificate what kind of delay time I prefer for every agents. How could I do? Thank you
I tried with some code of Java script but I think that scripture could be available only for the section "Actions" in the different boxes

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, it may be not quite efficient but seems doing what you want to achieve.

1. create a new agent type and leave all the configurations default. In my case it's named MyAgent.
2. make your two agent types to extend the MyAgent type. You can do this by going to the properties of your agent type, Avandced: extends other agent. Select MyAgent(or the agent type you have created in the 1. step) in the dropdown menu. [How to find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwRKh.png)
3. drag a Function from agent palette to the main, let's name it getServiceTime. Select the "returns value" option. In the arguments tab, add a new argument with Name "agent" and Type "MyAgent" (or the type you have created in the 1. step). In function body, write the following codes:

   ```
    if (agent instanceof Agent1) {
        return ((Agent1) agent).timeOfService;
    }else{
        return ((Agent2) agent).timeOfService;
    }
   ```

It's assumed that the two agent types are named as Agent1 and Agent2, the parameters in the agent types are named as timeOfService. Just change them to how you named your own types.
The if statement checks if the given agent is type of Agent1, if true, it returns the parameter value of Agent1, otherwise it returns the parameter value of Agent2.
[The configurations of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DK6q.png)

4. In the delay block, set the delay time as `getServiceTime(agent)`. Now the delay time should depend on what type of agent it is, since every time a new agent comes in, it calls the function getServiceTime(agent) and set its delay time correspondingly.

To check if it returns the right value, you can add `traceln(delay.getDelayTime(agent));` in the "on enter" field of the delay block, then you can get a blick of the delay time for the incoming agent at the console during the simulation.

This is my first answer and I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most basic functionalities so check the tutorials as well, but here goes:

Add a parameter 'myParameter' in your agent type of type double.

Give the agents different values for that parameter (cab be dine in the source or where ever you instantiate your agents)

In the delay block code section, use 'agent.myParameter' to access and apply that agent-specific duration.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand so well (I'm not an expert). First of all I have my two agents with their parameters "TimeOfService", and I have 2 blocks source, that work respectively with agent1 and agent2. The two block are connected with the block delay. So after adding the two parameters what I have to do? (I'm not so pratical with code Java, sorry) Thank You!

Comment: Hey Peitro, please first do (all) the step-by-step tutorials, they cover many of the basics of AnyLogic. Also check the AnyLogic YouTube channel, there are tons of beginner resources out there covering these things :)

Comment: Here is a video directly relating to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88D95QYtduM

Comment: I have already did all the tutorials on Anylogic Help, especially the tutorial on Queuing System and Agents Model, but I can't find a way to solve my specific problem. I don't know where to look yet :(

Comment: OK, but the Youtube Video is explaining exactly what you need. And the tutorials also cover that. You need to understand agent types and how you can access them from within flow chart blocks...