# How should agents separated by selectOutput be treated with different values?

Tags: anylogic

I'm getting a lot of help from this site in the process of modeling AnyLogic.
I have a question.
The repair times for each module are different, and if one of the modules 1 to 5 fails with a certain probability, it will be sent to delay (Module Repair 1).

[My Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyoUW.png)

When delay(ModuleRepair1) receives a specific module, how do I model the time when each module can be repaired?
For example, if delay(ModuleRepair1) receives module 3, it takes triangular(0.5,1,1.5) day, and if module 5 is received, it takes exp(3).

Thank you. sincerely.

Do I have to deal with this as a function?
I'm asking because I don't know much about anylogic. I'm sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different delay time for different agents in Anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74813569/different-delay-time-for-different-agents-in-anylogic)

Comment: This link is similar to my question. But I don't know what to input each object from selectOutput5 into the function.
Thank you.

Comment: read the answers properly... you are lacking a very basic anylogic feature, which is to add a variable inside an agent, the variable can define the time in the delay

Comment: I really appreciate, Felipe.